# UI Issue in Layout in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I am trying out product details page. Similar to this:

[image]

The UI look perfect and nice. The only issue is that I am trying to center the list of images.

[image]

The image in the box are not in the center. Tried the gravity/layout_gravity but still not able to get the same result. Can somebody tell me what could be wrong?

Here is my part of XML:

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageRelativeLayout"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelProductName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:ems="12"
                android:text="Over Panel Patch with Pivot"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/labelProductModel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/labelProductName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:ems="12"
                android:text="OSSPF-1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageProduct"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/labelProductModel"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:padding="4dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listImages"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageProduct"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/favImage"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_heart"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/shareImage"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/favImage"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you mean `the image in a box` is an item of RecyclerView right?

Comment: Yes. It is in RecyclerView. I would like to have RecyclerView to center of the screen. It is Left most now..

Comment: sorry, i cannot see it Left most :(. can you explain more in your screenshot

Comment: The whole list (BOX) is startng from left. I would like to show it like the actually hardrive docking screenshot.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh: I am talking RecyclerView and not the item in the RecyclerView

Comment: ok now, I see you recycleview is in the bottom and it center in horizontal
(the space to left is 16dp, and the space to right is 16dp). why you think you RecycleView is Left most
 sorry if I miss somthing.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh: Didn't understand 16dp part?

Comment: your linearlayout padding is 12dp, and you recycleview padding is 4dp

Comment: padding over all is 12dp the layout also has text for product name etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98953/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-sanjana-nair).

Comment: @PhanVănLinh : All I want is have recyclerview to center? how is this possible? I am not able to do it?

Comment: again, what do you mean in recycleview in center. what is the width of recycleview, how many space to left and how many space to right

Answer (score 0):

You can try this attribute for your imageView:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```